# PhpStorm keep "scanning files to index"

Tags: intellij-idea, indexing, phpstorm

PhpStorm keep "scanning files to index":

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fleet/rpc/client/SocketImplKind**

log file found

```
2021-12-23 12:05:38,284 [ 527156]   INFO - tellij.wsl.fs.WslContentLoader - fleet/rpc/client/SocketImplKind 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fleet/rpc/client/SocketImplKind
    at com.intellij.wsl.fs.WslFsdServer$Companion.start(WslFsdServer.kt:39)
    at com.intellij.wsl.fs.WslFsdServerHub$getWslFsd$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.apply(WslFsdServerHub.kt:27)
    at com.intellij.wsl.fs.WslFsdServerHub$getWslFsd$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.apply(WslFsdServerHub.kt:9)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1134)
    at com.intellij.wsl.fs.WslFsdServerHub.getWslFsd(WslFsdServerHub.kt:26)
    at com.intellij.wsl.fs.WslFsdServerHub.callFsApi(WslFsdServerHub.kt:14)
    at com.intellij.wsl.fs.WslContentLoader.getInputStream(WslContentLoader.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.getInputStream(LocalFileSystemBase.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeDetectionService.readFirstBytesFromFile(FileTypeDetectionService.java:577)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeDetectionService.lambda$new$5(FileTypeDetectionService.java:568)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.DiskQueryRelay.lambda$accessDiskWithCheckCanceled$0(DiskQueryRelay.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Hard to say anything for sure from one log snippet, however, it could be this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277575

Try installing the PhpStorm 2021.3.1 Preview build, the aforementioned issue should be fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

**The error happened after I install an antivirus software.**

The antivirus software started to scan my computer, and suggested a few old software packages. Then it fixed the "issues".

After that, I got this problem.
I think the antivirus software deleted some files required by phpstorm.

I reinstall windows 11, then the problem gone.